# Why does the Rails Guides say has_many :through implements a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

To me it appears a nested one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example: post has_many tags through taggings. (and tags have_many posts through taggings)

So, a post can be assigned to multiple tags:

```
@post << tag_one
@post << tag_two
```

And each tag can have many posts:

```
@tag.posts #=> [post_one, post_two]
```

The taggings table likely looks like

```
id, post_id, tag_id
```

There you go!

So, since both post and tag can have many of the other, many-many

Comment: That's right Jesse. I understood just after posting the question.